# Zeroing everything except formulas and text in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way within excel to clear a sheet of all numbers, but leave behind text and formulas?

To elaborate:  I mean cells that contain ONLY numbers.  If a cell contains text and numbers (like "Period 1") it can stay.

Edit:  Just to be clear: I'm not asking for the values that formulas evaluate to to remain.  that would be silly.  I am asking for the formulas themselves to remain.  the text of the formula.   So that the zeroed page still has formulas ready for data to be added to the zeroed cells. and produce the result of the formula.

Comment: The formulas would automatically recalculate, so you can't possible get rid of all the numbers and leave formulas.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I know the formulas will re-calculate but I want the formula to remain, not the data it calculates to.  So if cell a1 contained '345 and cell 2 contained '678' ' and cell a3 contained '=(a1 + a2)' I want cells a1 and a2 to be empty and cell a3 to still contain '=(a1 + a2)'.. so that in the future when cells a1 and a2 are populated again the sum in a3 is still present to produce a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select the region or entire sheet where you want to clear the numbers.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to bring uo the Go To dialog box.
3. Select `Special...`
4. Select `Constants` and `Numbers` (be sure to deselect Text, Logicals and Errors).
5. Select `OK` - now your selection will be reduced to just the cells that contain numbers.
6. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the contents of the selected cells.

[image: Excel's Go To Special dialog box]

Comment: Seems like Deletion is a little extreme, maybe just right click and 'Clear Contents' on the selection.  But since it works for the OP, I guess it's ok.

Comment: Deletion works for me.  If it deletes anything it shouldn't I can just ctrl-z.   I have a file containing many sheets each containing lots of text and formulas and data.  We 'reuse' the same file for new periods so this requires removing the data but keeping the formulas. Mike's solution saves me a LOT of time and hassle.

Comment: @Lance Roberts, as I understand it, pressing the Delete key on a selection is the same as clearing the contents. Right-clicking and selecting Delete (shifting cells up/left) is much more extreme, but that wan't what I was suggesting. I've rephrased step 6 to make this a little clearer.